# PHP Calculate polygon around polyline

Tags: php, maps, polygon, geocoding, polyline

I need to calculate polygon cords around polyline using PHP.

So the input looks like

```
[42.8476193, -78.8186415]
[42.8476193, -78.8186415]
[42.8476974, -78.8183599]
[42.847746, -78.818281]
[42.84806, -78.81784]
[42.848293, -78.817524]
[42.848507, -78.817246]
[42.848708337614, -78.816972090002]
[42.848710725944, -78.816968742025]
```

output would be cords of polygon of given width.

shown on the MAP below.. this should calculate the cords of the green polygon based on the polyline (blue) cords

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Let *a* and *b* be two consecutive points on your polyline. Construct the vector v=*b*-*a* which points from *a* to *b*. Normalize v to have length 1; I'll still call it v.
Rotate v 90 degrees counterclockwise. If v = (x,y), then vrot = (-y,x). Finally,
generate the points *a* + w vrot and *b* + w vrot, where w is the half-width of your corridor. Do the same for clockwise rotation, vrot = (y,-x).

Comment: Always share code if you want to help